# train nltk classifier for just one label

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, classification, nltk

I am just starting out with nltk, and I am following the book. Chapter six is about text classification, and i am a bit confused about something. In the examples (the names, and movie reviews) the classifier is trained to select between two well-defined labels (male-female, and pos-neg). But how to train if you have only one label.

Say I have a bunch of movie plot outlines, and I am only interested in fishing out movies from the sci-fi genre. Can I train a classifier to only recognize sci-fi plots, en say f.i. if classification confidence is > 80%, then put it in the sci-fi group, otherwise, just ignore it.

Hope somebody can clarify, thank you,

Comment: You should usually classify as positive at >.5, not .8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply train a binary classifier to distinguish between **sci-fi** and **not sci-fi**

So train on the movie plots that are labeled as **sci-fi** and also on a selection of all other genres. It might be a good idea to have a representative sample of the same size for the other genres such that not all are of the **romantic comedy** genre, for instance.

Comment: I see. Actually a bit more obvious than i thought, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I see two questions

1. How to train the system?
2. Can the system consist of "sci-fi" and "others"?

The answer to 2 is yes. Having a 80% confidence threshold idea also makes sense, as long as you see with your data, features and algorithm that 80% is a good threshold. (If not, you may want to consider lowering it if not all sci-fi movies are being classified as sci-fi, or lowering it, if too many non-sci-fi movies are being categorized as sci-fi.)

The answer to 1 depends on the data you have, the features you can extract, etc. Jared's approach seems reasonable. Like Jared, I'd also to emphasize the importance of enough and representative data.

Comment: P.S. By the way, notice that they talk about "male" and "female" as being two labels. "Pos" and "neg" are two other labels, so really we're talking about four labels/classes/categories in total!

Comment: Thanks amp, I accepted Jared's answer just because he was a bit sooner, but both your answers make sense. Although I don't understand your P.S., because in the book they are treated as separate examples.

Comment: No worries! Initially I read your question as if all the labels were in a single example, in which case we would have been talking about four labels. With your clarification, saying that there's two labels makes sense.